# Elasticsearchs- start with or contains on double analyezd field

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nosql

I am trying to make a query that gives all the the docoments start-with or contains in analayezd double field.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your use case? Can you show your current mapping type and the query you have so far? It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide more information.

Comment: price: { "type"  :  "double"}

i have nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards should be applied on not analyzed fields. You could add a subfield with type `keyword`, and then use a `wildcard` query.

However, there is a more efficient solution using ngrams. So you could configure this subfield with the `ngram` tokenizer.  See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html